# Output CMD command line to file does not work on Windows XP VM

Tags: windows-xp, virtualization, cmd.exe

I install a Windows XP virtual machine on Window 7 using VirtualBox.
I run a command within the VM: `ping www.google.com > file.txt` but no result found in the file. It is the same with all other commands. But the same commands work fine on the host machine. 
Can comeone explain me why this happen and how to output the result of a CMD command to a text file in the Windows XP virtual machine ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried giving an explicit output path?

```
ping www.google.com >C:\file.txt
```

Answer (score -1):

While this may not be the solution you're looking for, it is a solution nonetheless:

1. [Check out this page on how to install powershell on windows XP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/01/28/install-powershell-on-windows-xp-and-copying-files.aspx)
2. Type your command as such: `ping google.com | tee file.txt`.

It's worth noting that `tee` here is similar to *nix's `tee` but in the powershell world is actually an alias for Tee-Object. As such, the same command without the alias would be `ping google.com | Tee-Object file.txt`